# Using an image to change the segue

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode, swift, segue

I have a button that changes the segue to another view controller when it's tapped. I'd like to have an `image view` do the same thing— when tapped, change the segue. I've programmatically made the image tappable, it's just a matter of changing the segue now. I can't change the segue the way I'd normally do it (control+drag the button to the other view controller), as the second view controller doesn't highlight when I control+drag with the image. Does anyone know how I can change the segue using an image view? Thanks.

Comment: `UIButton` is a subclass on `UIView` just add you image view to the button as a subview. No need to make the image tappable and such.

Comment: just add a transparent clearcolor no text button above the image...

Comment: @Pete42 That did it, thanks! For any future viewers, I added an image view to my view controller then [chose my image from the attributes inspector](http://i.imgur.com/9bzeh8q.png).